# Create a data structure that can efficiently find missing combinations with a high score

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have N entities and I want to find all combinations of size 3 for these entities. The number of combinations is so large that it's impossible to actually compute all of them. So I'm going to use a heuristic: each entity has a score equal to the `(number of times this entity was used in a combination with the combination score >= threshold) / (number of times this entity was used in a combination)` and I want to find a combination that has a high probability of having `combination score >= threshold`. (Bonus points if you can find a combination with the highest score or can prove that the score is in some top percentile.)

Note that how to compute the combination score is hard to describe without giving a lot of context behind this problem, but suffice to say it's hard to predict and not fast to compute.

Since this is an ongoing process, I want to have a data structure where I can store each combination I try so that next time I can skip over them. This data structure should also help with finding potentially high scoring combinations I haven't tried yet.

A straight forward way to do this would be:

```
sorted_entities = sorted(entities, key=lambda entity: entity.score, reverse=True)
for e1 in sorted_entities:
  for e2 in sorted_entities:
    for e3 in sorted_entities:
      if not data_structure.already_have(e1, e2, e3):
        data_structure.add(e1, e2, e3)
        return (e1, e2, e3)
```

A few obvious problems:

- We're looking through all the high-scoring combinations we've looked at already before finding new ones.
- Depending on our scoring function it's not guaranteed that entities with the highest score will produce the highest scoring combination.

Another approach I can think of is probabilistic: pick a random entity with more chance of picking one with higher score. Then pick the next entity in proportion to the score of those two entities together. Then the optimal 3rd choice can be brute forced in O(N). (I think this sounds a lot like Bayesian Optimization, so that may be the best version of this approach.)

Comment: What is a "combination score" and how is it calculated?

Comment: @btilly That's what this part is addressing: "The scoring function is hard to describe without giving a lot of context behind this problem, but suffice to say it's hard to predict and not fast to compute." I'll edit it to make it more clear that it's talking about computing the combination score.

Comment: The right algorithm will entirely depend on the scoring function.  I would personally suggest some sort of "rating function" based on how much the element seems to help in scoring above a series of thresholds.  Then run a bunch of experiments to figure out what works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer I currently settled on:

Step 1) Find `e1` that has the least combinations using it.
Step 2) Find a list of combinations, `combos1`, that contain `e1`.
Step 3) Find `e2` that has the least combinations in `combos1` using it.
Step 4) Find a list of combinations, `combos2`, that contain `e1` and `e2` (Note: it'll be a strict subset of `combos1`.)
Step 5) Go through `combos2` and create a set of all entities that are used: `existing_e3_set`
Step 6) `set_of_all_entities` - `existing_e3_set` gives you all `e3`s that you can combine with `e1` and `e2` to create combinations that don't exist yet.

Runtime is linear in number of entities and combinations.
I think you can modify Steps 1 and 3 to use some kind of an entity score, but that I haven't thought through how that might lose the guarantee that you'll end up with a non-empty set in Step 6.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to help with checking if a combination already exists would be to use a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). You'd just need a hash function that takes a set of entities: something like `hash(list(sorted([e1, e2, e3])))`, although I haven't tried `hash({e1, e2, e3})` in Python.